# Attach author to POST request to create an object

Tags: django-rest-framework

It's probably very basic, but I am starting to learn Django REST Framework. So far I've succeeded with read-only operations. And now I got stuck on this problem.

I have a model:

```
class PersonComment(AbstractComment):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    body = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
```

(Here author is the author of the comment and person is a person this comment relates to; it's a genealogical site.) And a related serialiser:

```
class PersonCommentSerialiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PersonComment
        fields = ('url', 'body', 'person', 'author')
```

In my HTML page, I expect a user to submit a comment by providing "body", the rest should be auto-filled. What is the best practice for filling in the "author"? In my pre-DRF Django exercises, I was doing something like this in the view:

```
comment = PersonComment.objects.create(
    author=request.user,
    body=new_comment_body,
    person=person
)
```

But if I understand everything I've read so far, this is not the way in DRF. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the [default](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default) attribute in serializer fields.

```
class PersonCommentSerialiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = PersonComment
        fields = ('url', 'body', 'person', 'author')
```

[CurrentUserDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) is a class predefined in Django REST framework for exactly this purpose. This way you don't have to overwrite create in your own serializer.

I was not sure what is the difference between `person` and `author`. But you should be able to do something similar I suppose.